# Does Swift have a way to observe changes not just to an object, but to a reference?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on caching for an app using a subclass of `NSCache`. It's working well, though I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around how to update items in the cache when necessary and propagate those changes throughout the app. Say there is a model class, `Article`. An instance of `Article` is cached, and a few view controllers in the app are observing relevant properties on this instance with KVO, so when any changes are made to the properties of this `Article`, the changes automatically propagate.

But say another request for that `Article` is made, and the cached version is now stale. A request is made to the network and a new, updated instance is serialized, so the cache and the view controllers displaying the old instance need to be updated. How can I propagate this change to the view controllers? Is there a way to observe not just a property, but observe the reference itself to get notified when it changes? In other words, do something like `oldArticle = newArticle` and have an observer on the `oldArticle` fire?

I have a few ideas of how to handle it, but none I particularly like. I could individually transfer the property values of the new `Article` to the old one so the relevant observers are fired - yuck. I could use an object proxy, and set up an observer on the proxy when the object that it references changes. I could use `NotificationCenter` or set up some delegates or something to notify the view controllers of the update. But is there a simpler way to do something as described above?

Comment: "having a hard time wrapping my mind around how to update items in the cache when necessary and propagate those changes throughout the app" Haha, classic. Caching is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to observing the whole article is to make the cache a mutable dictionary (maybe yours is already) where the keys are something essential to the article (like an id) and the values are articles.  Observing view controllers can then observe both the cache's dictionary (where the key path is article id) -- to observe whole-article updates -- and any specific values they wish on the article itself.

Sticking with KVO, another approach is to give article and updateWith: (or copyFrom:) method that takes another article parameter, updating itself with the props from that parameter.  The VCs in this case will keep watching the same object, and their existing update logic will work.

Comment: Not a bad idea. But if I understand correctly, the observer for `modifiedAt` would still receive the old instance in its handler, and all the observing view controllers would have to fetch the new instance from the cache, which I'd like to avoid if possible. I guess I'm wondering if there's a way to have the new instance sent to the observing block, or the equivalent.

Comment: I'm using an `NSCache` subclass. I'm not sure I understand observing keys. Say the keys are of the pattern `"article\(article.id)"`. The key wouldn't change when an updated article comes in - it's the same article with the same id, just with a field or two updated. And I may end up doing something similar to your second recommendation, but that requires making `Article` properties `var` instead of `let`, which I'd prefer not to do. Though I guess they could be `private(set)`, I think.

Comment: Add a dictionary to your subclass and add id -> article pairs as you get them.  About observing keys - that's sloppy language on my part.  Observe that cache's dictionary at the key of the article id.  I'll edit.

Comment: I could do that, but that requires some overhead getting the view controllers to observe the cache's dictionary - right now, the view controllers and cache are unaware of each other, and I'd like to keep it that way. I think I like the idea of having an `updateWith:` method that the cache can call to update the article. Will accept if no better ideas come in.

Comment: Sure. Just remember that in order to observe the object itself changing, you must observe the object’s container. This implies knowledge one way or another of the cache. If this is a problem, consider my second idea. There, there is no vc code change, and no additional knowledge of the cache, just a new (but legit) responsibility for the fetch to recognize an update, and a new copy-like method on the article.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `ArticleUpdateDelegate`, and make your `ArticleViewController` conform. The VC then sets itself the delegate of your `Article`, so that whenever the article is updated, you notify the VC, which can then update its view, and do whatever else it needs.

Comment: Hm. But if several view controllers are sharing the article, they can't each simultaneously be the delegate, so changes don't propagate the same way as KVO. And how would this solve not just an update to the old article's properties, but a new article altogether?

Comment: @cweber105 Ah, good point. Hmmm I think this is probably a good fit for the observable pattern, from RxSwift or Combine. Have your VCs subscribe themselves to article provider objects, whose job it is to "stay up to date" and emit new article versions as they become available

Comment: Yea, I quickly bumped into reactive frameworks when searching for solutions. I'll look into the observable pattern, though I'd like to do it with pure swift instead of a dependency. Any resources you know of that lay it out clearly?

Comment: Well in one way or another what you would end up with is a ghetto self-implemented observable framework, which I would advise against. Better to use something more fully-featured/tested/popular/well-documented. I would suggest you start with the WWDC videos on Combine. Even if you use Rx (which I think is a better choice today, due to Combine's very limited platform support), those videos give a great conceptual understanding. Some terms are different, but almost all the concepts map across 1:1

Comment: Ooo, didn't realize Combine was native. That's interesting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Well, it's just Swift code. It's first-party, but it's no more native than Alamofire. It's a pretty nice framework, but documentation is sparse, and it's platform support is terrible. Its not available pre-mac Catalina, iOS 13, and it's not available at all on Linux. It's embarrassing. It won't really be mainstream usable for a few more years, but Rx is here today